# Sum up different columns for different groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing information about the activities of some organisations in different countries. The column *orga* contains the name of the organisations, *c1* to *c4* are country-columns containing the number of activities an organistion is doing in the country, and *home* is the organisation's country of residence. Values in *home* correspond to numbers in the column names of *c1* to *c4*.

```
orga <- c("AA", "AB", "AC", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD")
c1 <- c(3,1,0,0,2,0,1)
c2 <- c(0,2,2,0,1,0,1)
c3 <- c(1,0,0,1,0,2,0)
c4 <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0)
home <- c(1,2,3,2,1,3,1)
df <- data.frame(orga, c1, c2, c3, c4, home)
```

I know want to add an additional column *foreign*, containing information about all of an organisations foreign activities, summing up all activities mentioned in *c1* to *c4* but **not** in the column of the own country. So, the function should not sum up all the country-columns, but only the ones that are not the home-country. For example, if home=1 it should leave out c1, if home=2 leave out c2, etc.

In the example-case *foreign* should look like this:

```
df$foreign <- c(1,2,3,1,1,0,1)
```

**Is there a way to sum up columns for different groups, leaving out a different column for every group, and add the sums as new column to a dataframe?**

I already looked at the *group by* function of the dplyr-package, as well as *aggregate* and *tapply* in base-r, but couldn't come up with a solution. I would thus very much appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Did you got answer to your question ? If yes, you can select the answer as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  # Change the home column from number to character,
  # Make the ID (c1, c2, c3, c4) consistent to the column names from c1 to c4
  mutate(home = paste0("c", home)) %>%
  # Convert the data frame from wide format to long format
  # activity contains the columns names from c1 to c4 as labels
  # number is the original number for each
  gather(activity, number, -orga, -home) %>%
  # Remove rows when home and activity number are the same
  filter(home != activity) %>%
  # Group by the organization
  group_by(orga) %>%
  # Calculate the total number of activities, call it foreign
  summarise(foreign = sum(number)) %>%
  # Join the results back with df by organization
  left_join(df, by = "orga") %>%
  # Re-organiza the column
  select(orga, c1:home, foreign)
```

Here is the end result. The information you want is in the `foreign` column of the data frame `df2`.

```
# A tibble: 7 × 7
    orga    c1    c2    c3    c4  home foreign
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     AA     3     0     1     0     1       1
2     AB     1     2     0     1     2       2
3     AC     0     2     0     1     3       3
4     BA     0     0     1     0     2       1
5     BB     2     1     0     0     1       1
6     BC     0     0     2     0     3       0
7     BD     1     1     0     0     1       1
```

Comment: This is brilliant as it seems the most flexibel solution to me. Thank you for the nice explanation!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it using `rowSums`,

```
diag(as.matrix(rowSums(df[2:5])- df[2:5][df$home]))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `rowSums`.  Using `row/column` indexing, we replace the values to NA in a copy of the dataset and then with `rowSums` and `na.rm=TRUE` get the sum of the rows to exclude the 'home' column

```
df1 <- df
df1[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df), df$home)] <- NA
df$foreign <- rowSums(df1[2:5],na.rm=TRUE) 
df$foreign
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1 0 1
```

---

Or using `apply`

```
df$foreign <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) sum(head(x, -1)[-x[5]]))
df$foreign
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1 0 1
```